# checkbox is not displaying checked (react native)

Tags: checkbox, react-native

I am using checkbox from react-native-element

When i check the box it dose not display checked 
how can i display it  ?
here is my code

```
 <View>
                    <FlatList data={all_national_number}
                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                        renderItem={({ item }) =>
                            <CheckBox

                                title={item} 
                                uncheckedIcon={<Image source={require('../../assets/unchecked.png')} />}
                           checkedIcon={<Image source={require('../../assets/checked.jpg')} />}

                                onPress={() => this._onSelect(item)}>
                            </CheckBox>

                        }>
                    </FlatList>
                    </View>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375940/how-to-handle-checkbox-fetching-from-json-using-react-native-element-checbox-wit

Answer (score 0):

It is not showing because you are missing a property called `checked` which should be either `true` or `false`. So, ideally your method `this._onSelect(item)}` should contain logic to alter the checked status.

Something on the lines of

```
onSelect = (item) => {
this.setState({ isChecked: true})
}
```

and in your checkbox, you need to add one more prop that is `checked={this.state.isChecked}`

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `checked` property on the checkbox

```
<CheckBox
  title='Click Here'
  checked={this.state.checked}
/>
```